# Sql Query To Get String Value As Time Difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement regarding time that is stored as string like the below:

```
    ID - FromTime - ToTime - Day - RoomNo
      1 - 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM - Sun - 202
      2 - 11:00 AM - 12:00 AM - Sun - 203
```

So what I am trying to do is to check in the table, a room has been allocated within a specified time, like if a room is allocated from 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM on Sun, then no other schedule would be there or available by that time on that specified day. It must not overlap  like 10:20 AM to 11:00 AM as from 10:00 AM, there is already a schedule. Again I've to make assure for other schedules on that specific day (Sun) like from 11:00 AM to 12:00 AM are also available. This is just required to do a validation.

That is it. I am trying to do it with SQL query and hoping it would be simple. So tried a query that is really not good enough (just for demo purpose):

```
SELECT * 
FROM AllocateRoom 
WHERE
    CONVERT(Time, FromTime) >= CONVERT(Time, '10:00 AM') 
    AND CONVERT(Time, ToTime) <= CONVERT(Time, '11:00 AM')
```

Is it actually possible to do it using a SQL query?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 (and newer) allows this conversion.

Comment: What is wrong with the query you tried?

Comment: You'll have problems when your ranges cross midnight. You're going to have to use the day of week in your logic. And then, of course, you still have Saturday to Sunday to consider when the week starts over. How many days of data are you storing?

Comment: As to the question of overlapping ranges: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestIfDateRangesOverlap You can find many other pages on that topic as well.

Comment: The above query only works for an example: 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM. But it does not check for 10:01 AM to 11:00 AM. It overlaps even a schedule is in the table between 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM.

Comment: That's not the right way to check for overlap which I why I gave you the link.

Comment: shawnt00 I was able to resolve it and thanks a lot for the link. By the way, post the link as an answer and let me mark it. Could you please remove the down vote if you can.

Comment: Did you also consider the problem with midnight and Saturday to Sunday?

Comment: shawnt00 yes, we were able to do it. Me and one of my friend took some time to implement and finally tried to make use of the link that you provided. It was for an ASP.NET MVC application. We considered the day, time and of course overlapping issue. We did it using C# and posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the following that we tried to implement and almost works well:

```
    string scheduleTime = "";
    bool found = false;

    foreach (AllocateRoom allocate in allocatedRooms)
    {
        DateTime existingFromTime = Convert.ToDateTime(allocate.FromTime);
        DateTime existingToTime = Convert.ToDateTime(allocate.ToTime);

        bool matchRoom = allocate.RoomNo == aAllocateRoom.RoomNo;
        bool matchDay = allocate.Day == aAllocateRoom.Day;

        bool matchFromTime = existingFromTime == nFromTime;
        bool matchToTime = existingToTime == nToTime;

        bool coverExistingRange = nFromTime < existingFromTime & nToTime > existingFromTime;
        bool coverExistingRange2 = nFromTime < existingToTime & nToTime > existingToTime;

        bool toTimeInTheRange = nToTime > existingFromTime & nToTime < existingToTime;
        bool fromTimeInTheRange = nFromTime > existingFromTime & nFromTime < existingToTime;

        bool matchTime = matchFromTime || matchToTime;
        bool coverTime = coverExistingRange || coverExistingRange2;
        bool overlapTime = toTimeInTheRange || fromTimeInTheRange;

        if (matchRoom & matchDay & (matchTime || overlapTime || coverTime))
        {
            scheduleTime = "Room " + allocate.RoomNo + " - " + allocate.Day + " " + allocate.FromTime + " - " + allocate.ToTime;
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (found)
    {
        message = scheduleTime + " has been already scheduled!";
        return message;
    }
```